# hide few mat-options angular materialize

Tags: angular, angular-material, materialize

I can see there is property hidden,
But when I try its property its not working

```
<mat-option 
  *ngFor="let item of itemlist" 
  [value]="item.Name" 
  [hidden]="true">
  <span>{{ item.Name }}</span>
</mat-option>
```

But above is not hiding.

What can I do to hide it, I need to hide few options depending on condition

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any such thing in the [`mat-select`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) docs.

Comment: You don't normally hide options, you exclude them from the options list by filtering them. Hiding them visually is kind of like cheating. You should remove the items you want to hide from 'itemList'. See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53065121/9226213) by Jorge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an `[ngStyle]` with your condition and set the `display` property to `block` or `none` accordingly.

An eg:

```
<mat-option 
  *ngFor="let item of itemlist; let i = index;" 
  [value]="item.Name" 
  [ngStyle]="{ display : i % 2 === 0 ? 'none' : 'block' }"
  <span>{{ item.Name }}</span>
</mat-option>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwyeaf?file=app/select-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this directive, as I am new so couldn't think of this one

Answer (score 4):

You could use ng-container and ngIf or filter the itemlist in your component.ts before displaying values

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemlist">
 <mat-option *ngIf="item.hidden === false" [value]="item.Name">
   <span>{{ item.Name }}</span>
 </mat-option>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: but it will hide span not the mat option

Comment: I am able to hide if this list, I want it for mat-option

Comment: ah yeah, sorrythen you should filter the itemlist in your component.ts, and then show mat-option